# jQuery API call (insert query) for each item in array

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

This is my first jump into using APIs and I've created a very simple REST API on my local machine with a very simple jquery front end. I am trying to figure out the best way in which to use my ajax post call to my API to create a new item in my database.

```js
// sample code:
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/first_attempt/api/product/create.php",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: {
    "client_name": "foo",
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "value": "2",
    "item": "report_viewer"
  },
  success: function(result) {
    bootbox.alert("Value has been added successfully.", showValues());
  },
  error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
  }
});
```

I want to be able to use this in a `for` loop but I am unsure how to do it with each call getting a response back from the API and not overloading the API with requests it then doesn't complete.

Any advice you could share would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not put AJAX calls in a loop. All it will do is flood your server with requests and make it unresponsive for a time. A much better idea is to aggregate the data which you were intending to send in multiple requests in to a single request. Then have your `create.php` logic handle all of the data in one hit.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the response. If I am understanding correct, you'd advise instead making one giant query? Is that not equally slow?

Comment: It's marginally slower per-request, but in terms of server scalability it's an order of magnitude better